# Django ListView with ModelForm local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm having a trouble with using modelform in my generic.ListView. When I post the form I get the error in the below. That was working with form.Form but when I changed into form.ModelForm , I got this error.

**Is there any way to create an object with ModelForm in generic.ListView ? **

The error;

```
local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class ActionCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Action 
        fields = ('client_owner', 'contact_owner', 'topic', 'action_type', 'quote_price', 'quote_currency', 'statement', 'result', 'opportunity_type', 'file') 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['client_owner'] =  forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, queryset=models.Client.objects.all(), label="", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
        self.fields['contact_owner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=models.Contact.objects.none(), label="", widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})) 
        self.fields['topic'] = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100, label="", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Topic'}))
        
        if 'client_owner' in self.data: 
            try:
                alan1 = int(self.data.get('client_owner')) 
                self.fields['contact_owner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=models.Contact.objects.filter(client_owner_id = alan1), label="", widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})) 
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk and self.instance.client_owner: 
            self.fields['contact_owner'].queryset = self.instance.client_owner.contact_client.order_by('name')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from . import forms
from . import models

class ActionListView(generic.ListView): # action-listview
    model = models.Action
    context_object_name = 'all_actions'
    template_name = 'crm/action_list.html'
    ordering = ['-created']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'submit_action_create_form' in self.request.POST:
            action_form = forms.ActionCreateForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            if action_form.is_valid():
                print("*** request.POST: ", request.POST)
                client_obj = action_form.cleaned_data['client_owner']
                contact_obj = action_form.cleaned_data['contact_owner']
                topic_obj = action_form.cleaned_data['topic']
                instance = models.Action.objects.create(user_owner = self.request.user, client_owner = client_obj, topic =  topic_obj)
                instance.contact_owner.set(contact_obj)
                instance.save()
            return redirect('action-detailview', slug=instance.slug)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ActionListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action_create_form'] = forms.ActionCreateForm
        return context
```

the full traceback;

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/actions/

Django Version: 4.0
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'crm.apps.CrmConfig',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\py projects\django norga asistant 03\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Programming\py projects\django norga asistant 03\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\py projects\django norga asistant 03\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\py projects\django norga asistant 03\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\py projects\django norga asistant 03\crm\views.py", line 107, in post
    return redirect('action-detailview', slug=instance.slug)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /actions/
Exception Value: local variable 'instance' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Where is `self.instance` defined ? I think you meant `self.pk` instead of `self.instance.pk` and similarly with others

Comment: you mean the forms.py ?

Comment: Yes in model form `__init__`

Comment: it's because of the chained dropdown. I think the problem is in views.py

Comment: Update question with full trace back

Comment: I updated the question with traceback

Comment: As the full traceback shows you, the problem is in your redirect after handling the form for a POST. In the case where your form is not valid, you never instantiate `instance` but still try to dereference it to get a redirect target. The usual idiom is to redisplay the form w/error messages rather than redirect at all when it's not valid. I don't remember offhand how to do that w/class based views, I expect it's in the examples in the docs though.

Answer (score 0):

Move the return in if statement and define a new return for failed for like this:

```
if action_form.is_valid():
    # rest of your code
    return redirect('action-detailview', slug=instance.slug)
else:
    return redirect ('/')
```

You can replace the `('/')` with the name of the url to which view `ActionListView` is linked to.

Comment: My wish to create an object in Action model. Your recommendation does not create an object, it just redirect me to base path.

Comment: The issue is not in my answer rather in your form as this statement `action_form.is_valid()` return False meaning your form validation is failing. I just fixed your current issue of `local variable referenced before assignment`

Comment: action_form.is_valid() does not returning false. I printed request.POST and I can see the data coming up my terminal. However, it's odd that I can not achieve to save them :)

Comment: Getting value in `self.request.POST` doesn't mean your form is valid just print `action_form.is_valid()` you would see it prints False. And to why it does so you can print error message with `action_form.errors`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but my question was to create a new object in my Action model.

Comment: No your question was to fix reference error that i fixed. Have you printed form errors ? Your action model creation code is inside if condition which will only be created if the action_form.is_valode return True.

Comment: See my question above and be aware: **Is there any way to create an object with ModelForm in generic.ListView ? **

Comment: There could be errors in your form and as i said print `action_form.errors` and submit it here